# What db structure fits for site builder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I need to build web application that will do:

1. build web pages.

   - build template for page.
2. add module(by module I mean ContacUs form, Search, Billing System...). Each module can be constructed by submodules or diveded to submodules
3. build module(add form, textbox, button...) and that all entered data by user could be saved in db

Can you advise me a DB structure that will contain it all

I looked some cms db, but it's NOT this.
Please, don't ask why I mess with it. I just need to build it.

Comment: Are you wanting a CMS or are you asking for a good way to structure your content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you DotnetNuke.
DotNetNuke is the leading Web Content Management Platform for Microsoft ASP.NET, powering over 600,000 production web sites worldwide. The flexible DotNetNuke platform functions as either a Web CMS or a web application development framework. Depending on your role within your organization, DotNetNuke provides powerful benefits to support your Web initiatives.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/125/Default.aspx